# Which sorting algorithm is best in terms of space complexity - Quick Sort or Insertion Sort?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, quicksort, insertion-sort

I know that the time complexity of quicksort is less than insertion sort.

I heard that quicksort has greater space complexity than insertion sort because of recursion stack. What's your take on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quick Sort and Insertion Sort both are **in-place** and **comparison-based** sorting algorithms.

None of the above two sorting algorithms demand extra space from you but the space complexity of **Insertion Sort** is **O(1)** because it uses few temporary variables during swapping.

But the space complexity of **Quick Sort** is **O(log(n))**, this is because after partitioning, the partition with the fewest element is (recursively)sorted first, requiring at most O(log(n)) space. And the other partition is sorted using **tail-recursion**, which doesn't add to the call stack.This keeps the stack depth bounded by O(log(n)).

Answer (score 3):

Insertion sort is an in-place sorting algorithm, meaning no auxiliary data structures, the algorithm performs only swaps within the input array. So the space complexity is O(1).In space-wise insertion sort is better.

Comment: As far as I know, Quicksort is also an in-place algorithm.

Comment: @PencilProgrammer: Correct. Or rather, it _can be written_ to work in-place (but does not have to be). It does need the stack though.

Comment: Quicksort will use O(logn) for the stack memory. So it will use additional memory outside the array scope.

Comment: The term "in-place sort" means just that the _elements_ are not stored outside the array in temporary storage, not that no other memory is used.

Comment: Does stack memory used in successive recursive calls have any role in determining the space complexity?

Comment: Space complexity includes all types of memory usage.

Comment: @Thuvarakan: I do not disagree with that. I disagree with your using "in-place" as a distinction between InsertionSort and QuickSort. QuickSort is O(log N) algorithm that can be in-place or not; InsertionSort is O(1) algorithm that is always in-place. Being in-place or not has zero bearing on the space complexity.

Comment: It all depends on the definition of the "in-place" algorithm. If we define "in-place" in strict form as the algorithm can only have a constant amount of extra space, then quicksort is not "in-place". If we define "in-place" in more generic form as "does not move the data outside the input structure", then quicksort is again not "in-place".